How to run async function in celery task?
I have a problem when putting the upload function into celery through my endpoint with fastapi. Here is my code:
@
app.task
def upload_zip_file(uploadchunck_func, 
                    dataset_id: UUID,
                    file: UploadFile,
                    user_id: UUID):
    duplicate_count, duplicate_filenames = async_to_sync(uploadchunck_func.group_send)(dataset_id,file, user_id)
    return duplicate_count, duplicate_filenames

uploadchunck_func is the function that I want to process to the uploaded file which is the async function
I already use async_to_sync from heretext but it's not working.
This is the error:
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 41, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 63, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls, **dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 47, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 436, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 78, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 92, in __call__
    await self.simple_response(scope, receive, send, request_headers=headers)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 147, in simple_response
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/opt/autocare/app/api/api_v2/endpoint/datasets/uploads.py", line 163, in update_dataset_upload2
    return await dataset_service.upload_chunks_2(
  File "/opt/autocare/app/v2_service/dataset_service.py", line 1617, in upload_chunks_2
    task = upload_zip_file.delay(self._upload_chunks,
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 444, in delay
    return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 594, in apply_async
    return app.send_task(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/base.py", line 798, in send_task
    amqp.send_task_message(P, name, message, **options)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py", line 517, in send_task_message
    ret = producer.publish(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 175, in publish
    body, content_type, content_encoding = self._prepare(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 268, in _prepare
    body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 219, in dumps
    with _reraise_errors(EncodeError):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 45, in _reraise_errors
    reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/exceptions.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 41, in _reraise_errors
    yield
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 220, in dumps
    payload = encoder(data)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 63, in dumps
    return _dumps(s, cls=cls, **dict(default_kwargs, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 47, in default
    return super().default(o)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

Can anyone fix this?

kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable means that you are trying to pass a method/function to a Celery task, OR, you are returning a result object that contains a method/function. - This is not going to work. Instead you should pass some flag (even a string could work i think) that tells your Celery task which function/method to use.
